# asp.net mvc request xml from several providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc application that in one point i need to retrieve some XML files from some of my providers. How can i achieve this? Does it support multi-threading? The files will then be parsed and added to a database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it supports multithreading. To achieve it, you can use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[5]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParseXml()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParseXml()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParseXml()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParseXml())
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParseXml())
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

where ParseXML - is your method to parse xml and then you can save it to database

Comment: Good morning, does the same work if instead of the parsexml i use a httprequest and wait for a response?

Comment: Thanks just wanted to ask and be sure because of the time needed from a response to come in from an httprequest.